# Error at creating new resource with Julia-Genie

Tags: julia

In Genie (http://genieframework.com/),

I try to create a new resource names 'Toto' using the command

```
./bin/repl --resource:new=Toto
```

I get the following error :

```
ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: SearchLight not defined
execute(::Genie.Configuration.Settings) at /home/vlaugier/.julia/v0.6/Genie/src/Commands.jl:38
run() at /home/vlaugier/.julia/v0.6/Genie/src/Genie.jl:52
eval(::Module, ::Any) at ./boot.jl:235
eval_ew_expr at ./distributed/macros.jl:116 [inlined]
(::Base.Distributed.##135#136{Base.Distributed.#eval_ew_expr,Tuple{Expr},Array{Any,1}})() at ./distributed/remotecall.jl:314
run_work_thunk(::Base.Distributed.##135#136{Base.Distributed.#eval_ew_expr,Tuple{Expr},Array{Any,1}}, ::Bool) at ./distributed/process_messages.jl:56
#remotecall_fetch#140(::Array{Any,1}, ::Function, ::Function, ::Base.Distributed.LocalProcess, ::Expr, ::Vararg{Expr,N} where N) at ./distributed/remotecall.jl:339
remotecall_fetch(::Function, ::Base.Distributed.LocalProcess, ::Expr, ::Vararg{Expr,N} where N) at ./distributed/remotecall.jl:339
#remotecall_fetch#144(::Array{Any,1}, ::Function, ::Function, ::Int64, ::Expr, ::Vararg{Expr,N} where N) at ./distributed/remotecall.jl:367
remotecall_fetch(::Function, ::Int64, ::Expr, ::Vararg{Expr,N} where N) at ./distributed/remotecall.jl:367
(::##13#15)() at ./distributed/macros.jl:102
#remotecall_fetch#140(::Array{Any,1}, ::Function, ::Function, ::Base.Distributed.LocalProcess, ::Expr, ::Vararg{Expr,N} where N) at ./distributed/remotecall.jl:340
remotecall_fetch(::Function, ::Base.Distributed.LocalProcess, ::Expr, ::Vararg{Expr,N} where N) at ./distributed/remotecall.jl:339
#remotecall_fetch#144(::Array{Any,1}, ::Function, ::Function, ::Int64, ::Expr, ::Vararg{Expr,N} where N) at ./distributed/remotecall.jl:367
remotecall_fetch(::Function, ::Int64, ::Expr, ::Vararg{Expr,N} where N) at ./distributed/remotecall.jl:367
(::##13#15)() at ./distributed/macros.jl:102
sync_end() at ./task.jl:287
macro expansion at ./distributed/macros.jl:112 [inlined]
anonymous at ./<missing>:?
include_from_node1(::String) at ./loading.jl:576
include(::String) at ./sysimg.jl:14
(::Base.Distributed.##135#136{Base.#include,Tuple{String},Array{Any,1}})() at ./distributed/remotecall.jl:314
run_work_thunk(::Base.Distributed.##135#136{Base.#include,Tuple{String},Array{Any,1}}, ::Bool) at ./distributed/process_messages.jl:56
#remotecall_fetch#140(::Array{Any,1}, ::Function, ::Function, ::Base.Distributed.LocalProcess, ::String, ::Vararg{String,N} where N) at ./distributed/remotecall.jl:339
remotecall_fetch(::Function, ::Base.Distributed.LocalProcess, ::String, ::Vararg{String,N} where N) at ./distributed/remotecall.jl:339
#remotecall_fetch#144(::Array{Any,1}, ::Function, ::Function, ::Int64, ::String, ::Vararg{String,N} where N) at ./distributed/remotecall.jl:367
remotecall_fetch(::Function, ::Int64, ::String, ::Vararg{Any,N} where N) at ./distributed/remotecall.jl:367
(::Base.##507#509{Base.JLOptions})() at ./task.jl:335
while loading /home/vlaugier/CODE/sandbag/julia/genie/first_app_in_genie/genie.jl, in expression starting on line 32
#remotecall_fetch#140(::Array{Any,1}, ::Function, ::Function, ::Base.Distributed.LocalProcess, ::String, ::Vararg{String,N} where N) at ./distributed/remotecall.jl:340
remotecall_fetch(::Function, ::Base.Distributed.LocalProcess, ::String, ::Vararg{String,N} where N) at ./distributed/remotecall.jl:339
#remotecall_fetch#144(::Array{Any,1}, ::Function, ::Function, ::Int64, ::String, ::Vararg{String,N} where N) at ./distributed/remotecall.jl:367
remotecall_fetch(::Function, ::Int64, ::String, ::Vararg{Any,N} where N) at ./distributed/remotecall.jl:367
(::Base.##507#509{Base.JLOptions})() at ./task.jl:335
Stacktrace:
 [1] sync_end() at ./task.jl:287
 [2] macro expansion at ./task.jl:303 [inlined]
 [3] process_options(::Base.JLOptions) at ./client.jl:279
 [4] _start() at ./client.jl:371
```

Nevertheless some files are created :

- app/resources/totos/TotosController.jl
- app/resources/totos/TotosChannel.jl
- app/resources/totos/authorization.yml
- test/unit/totos_test.jl

My version of Julia is the following :

```
julia> versioninfo()
Julia Version 0.6.2
Commit d386e40c17 (2017-12-13 18:08 UTC)
Platform Info:
  OS: Linux (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
  CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3520M CPU @ 2.90GHz
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  BLAS: libopenblas (USE64BITINT DYNAMIC_ARCH NO_AFFINITY Sandybridge)
  LAPACK: libopenblas64_
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-3.9.1 (ORCJIT, ivybridge)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for that, it seems that the process of extracting the SearchLight ORM out of Genie broke the `Commands` module. I pushed a quick fix for this, you'll get it when you run `Pkg.update()`.

However, this is no longer the recommended way to interact with `Genie`'s generator features. Instead, start a Genie REPL (`$> ./bin/repl`) and then use the methods exposed by the various modules. Every piece of functionality provided at the shell is available under:

- `Genie.Generator` (`new_resource`, `new_controller`, `new_channel`)
- `SearchLight.Generator` (`db_init`, `new_model`, `new_migration`)
- `Migration`
- `Toolbox`
- `AppServer`

The `Commands` module is left for historical reasons - and because it seemed a good way to help with feature discovery, lacking extensive documentation. Once better docs become available, more such early features will be removed or refactored/reorganized.

Finally, for any other bugs, please open an issue in Genie's GitHub repo.